# Fresh re-install of rockbox on MP3 player causes "error accessing playlist control file" when unplugged

Tags: rockbox

Occasionally Rockbox on my MP3 player (Sansa Clip Zip) seems to play up.  I clear the settings and re-install Rockbox.

After re-installing it this time, I noticed "error accessing playlist control file", when I unplug the USB cable.  Why?

Software version:

- Rockbox 3.13
- Rockbox Utility (install) 1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was happening because the playlist control file `.rockbox/.playlist_control` does not exist.

Once you've played a file, the error goes away.